# Synchronization between two sql express server

Tags: c#, guid, sql-server-express, uuid, microsoft-sync-framework

I need to be able to sync mainDB server with clientDB server,whenever client press sync button. Whenever conflict occurs i want to preserve insertion/deletion made by both client and master.I'm using sync framework.
**EDIT**
Auto increment primary key creates problem.Is it necessary to use GUID/UUID as primary key.Or is there any other solution?

Comment: go for sync framework

Answer (score 2):

If you only have two SQL Server Express Edition instances then your best option is [Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb736753.aspx) since Merge Replication requires at least one instance to be Standard Edition or higher to act as the Publisher.  A SQL Server Express Edition instance can only function as a Subscriber.

If you have a Standard Edition or higher license then Merge Replication would be the easiest solution to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks!suggest me some sample code related to synchronization in SQL Express.I have gone through msdn(Walkthrough: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Express) –

Comment: The best place for Sync Framework code samples is Sync Framework Samples (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902852.aspx) and the MSDN Code Gallery (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f[0].Type=SearchText&f[0].Value=Microsoft%20Sync%20Framework&f[1].Type=Affiliation&f[1].Value=Official&f[1].Text=Microsoft).

Comment: @BrandonWilliams is there any way to do this using .net framework 4.5, the sync framework i guess works on 2.0